# WooCommerce - register second user in woocommerce_created_customer hook

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm coming across an issue when trying to register a second user account once someone registers as a customer via WooCommerce. I have added the following woocommerce_created_customer hook:

```
add_action('woocommerce_created_customer', function($customer_id)
{
    if(isset($_POST['second_user_first_name']) && isset($_POST['second_user_last_name']))
    {
        $createSecondUserId = wp_create_user(strtolower($_POST['second_user_first_name'].'-'.$_POST['second_user_last_name']).'-'.$customer_id, wp_generate_password(), 'test@test.com');

        if(is_wp_error($createSecondUserId))
        {
            $errors = $createSecondUserId->errors;

            print_r($errors);
            die();
        }
    }
});
```

However I get the following error when submitting a new WooCommerce registration:

```
Array ( [existing_user_login] => Array ( [0] => Sorry, that username already exists! ) )
```

It's strange as I'm setting a random username within the wp_create_user function, so the usernames should not clash. Has anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [username_exists()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/username_exists/) to determines that the given username exists.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_created_customer', function($customer_id){

    if( isset( $_POST['second_user_first_name'] ) && isset( $_POST['second_user_last_name'] ) ) {

        if( !username_exists( strtolower( $_POST['second_user_first_name'].'-'.$_POST['second_user_last_name'] ).'-'.$customer_id ) ){

            $createSecondUserId = wp_create_user( strtolower( $_POST['second_user_first_name'].'-'.$_POST['second_user_last_name'] ).'-'.$customer_id, wp_generate_password(), 'test@test.com' );

            if(is_wp_error($createSecondUserId)){

                $errors = $createSecondUserId->errors;
                print_r($errors);
                die();

            }

        }

    }

});
```

Comment: This didn't work unfortunately, I got the same outcome. There isn't a user with the username that I'm setting in the wp_create_user function, that's the strange thing

Comment: how do you access `$_POST`? do you try to print what you get in `$_POST`?

Comment: Yes, I've printed it to check the values. Even if I set the username to something random e.g. wp_create_user('testusername', ....  I still get the same error : (

Comment: How and when are you call this `woocommerce_created_customer` action?

Comment: I'm calling it in functions.php

Answer (score 0):

If the username already exists you can create a new one **by adding a progressive numeric suffix**. In this way you will be sure that the username of the second account **will always be unique**.

> Note that if you run multiple tests with your current code you need to
> make sure you remove the user with the email address **test@test.com**
> otherwise you will get an error: `[existing_user_email] => Sorry, that email address is already used!`.

```
add_action('woocommerce_created_customer', function( $customer_id ) {
    if ( isset($_POST['second_user_first_name']) && isset($_POST['second_user_last_name']) ) {
        // create the username based on the form data
        $username = strtolower( $_POST['second_user_first_name'] . '-' . $_POST['second_user_last_name'] ) . '-' . $customer_id;
        // if the username already exists it creates a unique one
        if ( username_exists($username) ) {
            $i = 0;
            while ( username_exists($username) ) {
                $username = $username . '-' . ++$i;
            }
        }
        // create the second user
        $createSecondUserId = wp_create_user( $username, wp_generate_password(), 'test@test.com' );
    }
});
```

*The code has been tested and works. Add it to your active theme's functions.php.*